# Windows XP: RegSvr32 /i:[cmdline]: What exactly is "Command line" in this case?

Tags: regsvr32

I am trying to register a dll using regsvr32 in a cmd window. I do this on an administrator account, but I need this dll to be registered for all the users. Turns out regsvr32 does not do that, it only registers for your current user. Well, when you use it this way anyways: "regsvr32 /i "C:\MyDll.dll"" What happens; The entry is added to Local_User, and Classes in the registry, but not Local_Machine.

The msdn article on regsvr32 says it also takes a [cmdline] when using the /i option. But the article fails to specify what I can put in place of [cmdline]. Google is refusing to help me as well, so I'm a bit stuck on this.

I realize this is not exactly on the topic of programming, but this is something programmers might know, so... Has anyone run into this before? Perhaps someone knows how this [cmdline] tag works? Are there any other ways to add this dll to all users? (Apart from editing the registry manually that is.) Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you put in place to [cmdline] is determined by the DLL you're registering. regsvr32 will just pass that text to a function called [DllInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759846(VS.85).aspx) in the DLL. If you want to know what to pass, you must consult the documentation for this particular DLL.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's very enlightening. It answers my question, but it doesn't solve my problem. Oh well, that's not your fault :)